# How to run bluestacks on windows when a docker installation is in place?

Tags: windows-10, docker, hyper-v, compatibility, bluestacks

I use `docker` for my work. It users Hyper-V.

I want now to install `bluestacks`. It complains about having Hyper-V activated.

Installed version is `BlueStacksInstaller_4.190.0.5002_native_30c0195e8145a840e2d4e604044cba80`.

After getting an error saying that the engine can't start and looking for some info on the Internet, I've seen this article:

https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041390952-How-to-run-BlueStacks-with-Hyper-V-enabled

It says it's a beta version, but really sepaking, the minor is lesser (180 instead of 190) and the release too (4203 instead of 5002). So this makes me think the article is old and the newer 4.190 version superseeded this one. Proposed download version is 4.180.0.4203_native_7576530aaaa81c33a40d3dad71eb79c4.

I've tried the same procedure but on the latest version (4.190): a) installing "as an administrator" and b) running the program also "as an administrator".

It still says "impossible to launch BlueStacks" because of Hyper-V problems:

[image]

## Questions

a) May I have docker and BlueStacks on the same computer?
b) How?

Answer (score 4):

Now, since a couple months ago is very possible to run Bluestacks along with Docker (I'm using it), you can check the info here: [How to use Bluestacks with Hyper-V](https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041390952-How-to-use-BlueStacks-on-Windows-10-with-Hyper-V-enabled) they enabled a new buidl with Hyper-V support and it's now official.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to run docker AND bluestacks together at this time (unless Bluestacks starts relying on HyperV)

Bluestacks uses its own virtualization, similar to what VirtualBox does, so when Hyper-V  is enabled it interferes with this.

That being said - apparently you can download a HyperV enabled version here (tho I haven't tested it myself):

http://cdn3.bluestacks.com/downloads/windows/bgp64_hyperv/4.200.0.4205/0c7c894214ebb7d4fb9b009472f54254/BlueStacksMicroInstaller_4.200.0.4205_native.exe?filename=BlueStacksInstaller_4.200.0.4205_native_e0175934c4a0a56f1db683585ffd1bcf.exe